# How to put SOAP response into UITableView?

Tags: ios, soap

I use SOAP webservices in my app. I make an request with the following statements (.m file):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad

{

    [super viewDidLoad];



    NSString *soapMsg =

    [NSString stringWithFormat:

     @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance>\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema>\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/>\"><soap:Body><retLoca xmlns=\"http://www.ctrlbase.nl/cbawebapp>\"><tcUser>112</tcUser></retLoca></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>"];



    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:

                  @"http://www.ctrlbase.nl/cbawebapp/getLoca.asmx>"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *req =

    [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];



    NSString *msgLength =

    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMsg length]];

    [req addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8"

forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    [req addValue:@"http://www.ctrlbase.nl/cbawebapp/retLoca>"

forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];

    [req addValue:msgLength

forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    [req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [req setHTTPBody: [soapMsg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];



    HUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];

    HUD.dimBackground = YES;

    HUD.labelText = @"Ophalen van gegevens";

    HUD.delegate = self;



    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];



     if( theConnection )

     {

          webData = [NSMutableData data];

     }

     else

     {

          NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");

     }





}



-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection

didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *) response {

    [webData setLength: 0];

}



-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection

    didReceiveData:(NSData *) data {

    [webData appendData:data];

}



-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *) connection {

    NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes: %d", [webData length]);

    NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc]

                        initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes]

                        length:[webData length]

                        encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    //---shows the XML---

    NSLog(theXML);



   if( xmlParser )

    {



    }



    xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:webData];

    [xmlParser setDelegate:self];

    [xmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:YES];

    [xmlParser parse];



    [HUD hide:YES];

}



-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict

{

    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"retLocaResponse"] ) {



        NSLog(@"Log Output%@",[attributeDict objectForKey:@"retLocaResult"]);

        NSString *strValue= [attributeDict objectForKey:@"retLocaResult"];



        if(strValue != (NSString*)[NSNull null])

        {

            [chunks addObject:[attributeDict objectForKey:@"retLocaResult"]];

        }

        else

        {



        }



        recordResults = YES;

}

}



-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:

(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{

    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"retLocaResponse"] ) {

        NSLog(@"Log array%@",chunks);

        [[self tableView]reloadData];



        recordResults = NO;



    }

}



- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {



    return [chunks count];

}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault    reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];

    }



    cell.textLabel.text =[chunks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



    return cell;

}
```

But I don't get the Location names into an UITableView. What do I wrong or what can I do to let this work. Please help me so I can finish my application.

### Thanks a lot!

EDIT for Samkit Jain: Crashes with the 'init' for the array.

LOG:

2013-08-09 00:12:31.631 Ctrlbase[776:c07] request finished
2013-08-09 00:12:31.904 Ctrlbase[776:c07] DONE. Received Bytes: 381
2013-08-09 00:12:31.904 Ctrlbase[776:c07] 0640. Home5 Cash & Carry
2013-08-09 00:12:32.028 Ctrlbase[776:c07] Log Output(null)
2013-08-09 00:12:32.159 Ctrlbase[776:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

-

Server request:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <retLoca xmlns="http://www.ctrlbase.nl/cbawebapp">
      <tcUser>string</tcUser>
    </retLoca>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Server response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <retLocaResponse xmlns="http://www.ctrlbase.nl/cbawebapp">
      <retLocaResult>string</retLocaResult>
    </retLocaResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: [myTableView reloadData];  Reload the table's data after you update your data source.

Comment: I have: [[self tableView]reloadData];

Comment: Somebody another tip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialize chunks in viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad

   {
       chunks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
      //same code here
   }
```

If this does not work.
Give me the complete log of your data coming from server and data from xml also.

Edit for Rick de Jong:
There is some problem in your getting data from server.
If you are not getting data from server, data can't be saved in array.
So, get your data properly from server.
When data will come properly from server :

```
-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *) connection {

    NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes: %d", [webData length]);

    NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc]

                    initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes]

                    length:[webData length]

                    encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];



    NSLog(@"Xml is :-----------%@",theXML); // This line should print your xml coming from from server

}
```

Give me that output, I will surely give you solution after that.

One more thing, when you are parsing data. your required data is coming in tags not as attribute of xml, as per your Soap. So you should use :

```
if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"retLocaResult"] ) {
   // code to save data and add to array
}
```

in didStartElement and didEndElement to get proper result.

One more error in your code remove >
in following code :

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:

              @"http://www.ctrlbase.nl/cbawebapp/getLoca.asmx"];
```

Finally I got the output :

Use this :

.h file

```
{
NSMutableData *webData;
NSXMLParser *xmlParser;
NSMutableArray *chunks;
BOOL recordResults;

NSMutableString *strCaptured;
}
```

.m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad

{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    chunks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSString *temp = @"112";

    NSString *soapMsg = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><soap:Body><retLoca xmlns=\"http://www.ctrlbase.nl/cbawebapp\"><tcUser>%@</tcUser></retLoca></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>",temp];

   // NSString *soapMsg = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance>\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema>\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/>\"><soap:Body><retLoca xmlns=\"http://www.ctrlbase.nl/cbawebapp\"><tcUser>112</tcUser></retLoca></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.ctrlbase.nl/cbawebapp/getLoca.asmx"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

    NSString *msgLength = [[NSString alloc ]initWithFormat:@"%d",[soapMsg length]];

    [theRequest addValue:@"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody:[soapMsg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    //[theRequest addValue:@"http://www.ctrlbase.nl/cbawebapp/retLoca>" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    if( theConnection )
    {
        webData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];            
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
    }
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection

didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *) response {

    [webData setLength: 0];

}


-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection

    didReceiveData:(NSData *) data {

    [webData appendData:data];

}

-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *) connection {

    NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes: %d", [webData length]);

    NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc]

                        initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes]

                        length:[webData length]

                        encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    //---shows the XML---

    NSLog(@"Xml is :-----------%@",theXML);

    if( xmlParser )
    {

    }

    xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:webData];

    xmlParser.delegate = self;

    [xmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:YES];

    [xmlParser parse];

}


- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
    strCaptured = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
}
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    recordResults = false;
    [strCaptured setString:@""];

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"retLocaResult"]) {
        recordResults = true;
    }


}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{

    recordResults = false;

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"retLocaResult"]){
        [chunks addObject:strCaptured];
    }

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if (recordResults
        ) {
        [strCaptured appendString:string];
    }
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [chunks count];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault    reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];

    }

    cell.textLabel.text =[chunks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: I posted the server response.

Comment: What to do with this response: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><retLocaResponse xmlns="http://www.ctrlbase.nl/cbawebapp"><retLocaResult>0250. Boulevard40|0380. Woonfabriek Cruquius|0390. Woonfabriek Amsterdam|0490. Depot Zeven|0640. Home5 Cash &amp; Carry|0750. Havenaer|0760. Lifestyle Depot Sluis|0780. Gaaf BV|0880. HDC Vianen</retLocaResult></retLocaResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>

Comment: Hey Rick,Can you tell me what is expected output from this?

Comment: Parse the data between tags < retLocaResult>then use 2 separators | and , to separate locations

Comment: So 0250. Boulevard40|0380. Woonfabriek Cruquius must be 0250. Boulevard40||0380. Woonfabriek Cruquius? What to do in the code?

Comment: I think 0250 shoul be Boulevard40, 0380 shoul be Woonfabriek Cruquius and so on...you can find substrings and then parse

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35377/discussion-between-rick-de-jong-and-samkit-jain)